# Exporting a photo to Instagram

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, instagram, uidocument

I am trying to export a photo from my application to Instagram, using this code:

```
// Capture Screenshot
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size,self.view.opaque,0.0);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/test.igo"];
NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", jpgPath]];
dic = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:igImageHookFile]];
dic.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";
dic.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"my caption" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
} else {
  NSLog(@"No Instagram Found");
}
```

But it is not working. It crashes with the following error:

> 2013-01-19 20:40:41.948 Ayat[12648:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

I am not sure I'm properly:

1- Saving jpgpath as the screenshot I took .

2- Passing the "dic" document to Instagram.

Comment: Define "not working". Compiler warning/error? Crash? What? Be specific. Have you used the debugger? Have you verified all of the variables have the expected values? What happens in the `if` statement?

Comment: maddy.. it crashes with the following error:

2013-01-19 20:40:41.948 Ayat[12648:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
I am not sure Im properly:
1- saving jpgpath as the screenshot i took
2- opening instagram with the "dic" document

Comment: Update your question with the additional details.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my app, I have also export photo to Instagram. (Image must be larger than 612x612 size)
Try this code:

```
-(void)shareImageOnInstagram:(UIImage*)shareImage
{
    //Remember Image must be larger than 612x612 size if not resize it.   

    NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];

    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL])
    {
        NSString *documentDirectory=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
        NSString *saveImagePath=[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.ig"];
        NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(shareImage);
        [imageData writeToFile:saveImagePath atomically:YES];

        NSURL *imageURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:saveImagePath];

        UIDocumentInteractionController *docController=[[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc]init];
        docController.delegate=self;
        [docController retain];
        docController.UTI=@"com.instagram.photo";

        docController.annotation=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Image Taken via @App",@"InstagramCaption", nil];

        [docController setURL:imageURL];


        [docController presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem animated:YES];  //Here try which one is suitable for u to present the doc Controller. if crash occurs

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog (@"Instagram not found");

    }

}
```

I hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. answered my questions and Worked perfectly

Comment: Hi i am using the same code but its not working on ios 8 does anyone has the same issue

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 2):

On this line

```
dic = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:igImageHookFile]];
```

you are calling `fileURLWithPath:`. For a start this expects an `NSString`, not an `NSURL`, but from your error message it looks like `igImageHookFile` is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

It took a bunch of research but I finally found this at this site that helped. I just trimmed it up a bit to not include the caption as that was his original problem... but if you're only putting in the picture, here it is:

```
-(void)shareImageOnInstagram
{
//Remember Image must be larger than 612x612 size if not resize it.
 NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]){
    NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", blendedImageURL];
    NSURL *imageUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: urlString];
    self.docController = [self setupControllerWithURL:imageUrl usingDelegate:self];
    self.docController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
   // self.docController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"I want to     share this text" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
    [self.docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect: self.view.frame inView: self.view     animated: YES ];}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code and it worked:

```
- (void) shareImageWithInstagram
{
    NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://"];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL])
    {
        UICachedFileMgr* mgr = _gCachedManger;
        UIImage* photoImage = [mgr imageWithUrl:_imageView.image];
        NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(photoImage);
        NSString* captionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",self.approvedData.approvedCaption,self.approvedData.tag];
        NSString* imagePath = [UIUtils documentDirectoryWithSubpath:@"image.igo"];
        [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:NO];
        NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@",imagePath]];

        self.docFile = [[self setupControllerWithURL:fileURL usingDelegate:self]retain];
        self.docFile.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: captionString
                                                         forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
        self.docFile.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";

        // OPEN THE HOOK
        [self.docFile presentOpenInMenuFromRect:self.view.frame inView:self.view animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [UIUtils messageAlert:@"Instagram not installed in this device!\nTo share image please install instagram." title:nil delegate:nil];
    }
}
```